# ef core 1.1.0 related entity async not inserted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

## EntityFramework core 1.1.0 async

```
var blog = new Blog
{
    Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet",
    Posts = new List<Post>
    {
        new Post { Title = "Intro to C#" },
        new Post { Title = "Intro to VB.NET" },
        new Post { Title = "Intro to F#" }
    }
};

await _dbContext.Set<Blog>().AddAsync(blog);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

### Generated Query

```
INSERT INTO [Blogs] ([Url])
VALUES (@p0);
SELECT [BlogId]
FROM [Blogs]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [BlogId] = scope_identity();
```

Why related object are not inserted when use  _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

## EntityFramework core 1.1.0 sync

```
var blog = new Blog
{
Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet",
Posts = new List<Post>
{
    new Post { Title = "Intro to C#" },
    new Post { Title = "Intro to VB.NET" },
    new Post { Title = "Intro to F#" }
}
};

_dbContext.Set<Blog>().Add(blog);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

### Generated Query

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Blogs] ([Url])
VALUES (@p0);
SELECT [BlogId]
FROM [Blogs]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [BlogId] = scope_identity();
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[@p1='?', @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (Size = 4000), @p4='?', @p5='?' (Size = 4000), @p6='?' (Size = 4000), @p7='?', @p8='?' (Size = 4000), @p9='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @toInsert0 TABLE ([BlogId] int, [Content] nvarchar(max), [Title] nvarchar(max), [_Position] [int]);
INSERT INTO @toInsert0
VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, 0),
(@p4, @p5, @p6, 1),
(@p7, @p8, @p9, 2);

DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([PostId] int, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [Posts] USING @toInsert0 AS i ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([BlogId], [Content], [Title])
VALUES (i.[BlogId], i.[Content], i.[Title])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[PostId], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [t].[PostId] FROM [Posts] t
INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[PostId] = [i].[PostId])
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];
```

I don't understand why **sync** work and **async** not work with related entities.

Is it a bug in entityframework core 1.1.0 ?
Any configuration ?

Comment: This is bug in EF Core 1.1 see issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7298
It is fixed in 1.1.1 patch which will be released soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry but i made a change for working

change

```
await _dbContext.Set<Blog>().AddAsync(blog);
```

to

```
_dbContext.Set<Blog>().Add(blog);
```

Comment: Someone can suggest me another solution ?

Comment: There is no good point in doing `await Task.Run(() => _dbContext.Set<Blog>().Add(blog))` instead of just `_dbContext.Set<Blog>().Add(blog)`.  There is also no reason to use `AddAsync()` even if you use `SaveChangesAsync()`; just use `Add()` instead.

Comment: Look at the [code comments](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/8de7857c9238a1aaf433e10ddfbe239faeb7e9dd/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/DbSet%60.cs) for the only reason to use `AddAsync()`: "This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo',to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used."